# How can I tell if my junction box will support a ceiling fan?

Tags: electrical

I want to install a drum type ceiling fan to the dining room ceiling of a new condominium I just bought. The drum type fan with a light weighs 24 lbs, as per the Home Depot website. How can I tell if the junction box will support this fan?

I would like not to have the electrician come twice i.e, first to look at the installation and then again, to install or maybe just tell me the fan unit is too heavy for the junction box.  The management cannot seem to tell me what the box will support.Thanks

Comment: Is it a metal box or plastic?  Picture, perhaps?

Comment: Either way, it should be one call for the electrician.  If they are coming to install a fan, they are going to have a replacement box that will hold it (or you called the wrong electrician).